# How to fix TypeError: sqlDb is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I have REST app using pure node.js I have created an HTML server that listens on port 8080 for a GET request.  IF the request endpoint is /employees, for example (http://localhost:8080/employees), the response should be a recordset of the employee table.  When I make the GET request for (http://localhost:8080/employees I am receiving the following error found is db.js: TypeError: sqlDb is not a constructor

I am stuck at this point and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the js code:

db.js

```
const sqlDb = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')
//const sqlDb = require('mssql')
var settings = require("../settings");

    exports.executeSql = function (sql, callback) {
        var conn = new sqlDb.ConnectionPool(settings.dbConfig);
        conn.connect()
            .then(function () {
                var req = new sqlDb(conn);
                req.query(sql)
                    .then(function (recordset) {
                        callback(recordset);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        callback(null, err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback(null, err);
            });
    };
```

server.js

```
const sqlDb = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')
    var http = require("http");
    var emp = require("../controllers/employees");
    const settings = require("../settings");

    http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
        switch (req.method) {
            case "GET":
                if (req.url === "/") {
                    resp.end();
                }
                else if (req.url === "/employees") {
                    emp.getList(req, resp);
                }
                break;
            case "POST":
                break;
            case "PUT":
                break;
            case "DELETE":
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }).listen(settings.webPort, function () {
        console.log("Server Started Listening at: " + settings.webPort);
    });
```

employees.js

```
var db = require("../core/db");

exports.getList = function (req, resp) {
    db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE", function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
            resp.writeHead(500, "Internal Error Occured", { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
            resp.write("<html><head><title>500</title></head><body500: Internal Error. Details: " + err + "></body></html>");
        }
        else {
            resp.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
            resp.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        resp.end();
    });
};

exports.get = function (req, resp, empno) {

};

exports.add = function (req, resp, reqBody) {

};

exports.update = function (req, resp, reqBody) {

};

exports.delete = function (req, resp, reqBody) {

};
```

settings.js

```
exports.dbConfig = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: '123abc',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'LWWEBAPP',
    port: 1433
};

exports.webPort = 8080;
```

This is the console.log(sqlDb);

```
{ ConnectionPool: [Function: ConnectionPool],
  Transaction: [Function: Transaction],
  Request: [Function: Request],
  PreparedStatement: [Function: PreparedStatement],
  ConnectionError: [Function: ConnectionError],
  TransactionError: [Function: TransactionError],
  RequestError: [Function: RequestError],
  PreparedStatementError: [Function: PreparedStatementError],
  Table:
   { [Function: Table]
     fromRecordset: [Function: fromRecordset],
     parseName: [Function: parseName] },
  ISOLATION_LEVEL:
   { READ_UNCOMMITTED: 1,
     READ_COMMITTED: 2,
     REPEATABLE_READ: 3,
     SERIALIZABLE: 4,
     SNAPSHOT: 5 },
  TYPES:
   { VarChar: [sql.VarChar],
     NVarChar: [sql.NVarChar],
     Text: [sql.Text],
     Int: [sql.Int],
     BigInt: [sql.BigInt],
     TinyInt: [sql.TinyInt],
     SmallInt: [sql.SmallInt],
     Bit: [sql.Bit],
     Float: [sql.Float],
     Numeric: [sql.Numeric],
     Decimal: [sql.Decimal],
     Real: [sql.Real],
     Date: [sql.Date],
     DateTime: [sql.DateTime],
     DateTime2: [sql.DateTime2],
     DateTimeOffset: [sql.DateTimeOffset],
     SmallDateTime: [sql.SmallDateTime],
     Time: [sql.Time],
     UniqueIdentifier: [sql.UniqueIdentifier],
     SmallMoney: [sql.SmallMoney],
     Money: [sql.Money],
     Binary: [sql.Binary],
     VarBinary: [sql.VarBinary],
     Image: [sql.Image],
     Xml: [sql.Xml],
     Char: [sql.Char],
     NChar: [sql.NChar],
     NText: [sql.NText],
     TVP: [sql.TVP],
     UDT: [sql.UDT],
     Geography: [sql.Geography],
     Geometry: [sql.Geometry],
     Variant: [sql.Variant] },
  MAX: 65535,
  map:
   [ { js: [Function: String], sql: [sql.NVarChar] },
     { js: [Function: Number], sql: [sql.Int] },
     { js: [Function: Boolean], sql: [sql.Bit] },
     { js: [Function: Date], sql: [sql.DateTime] },
     { js: [Object], sql: [sql.VarBinary] },
     { js: [Object], sql: [sql.TVP] },
     register: [Function] ],
  VarChar: [sql.VarChar],
  VARCHAR: [sql.VarChar],
  NVarChar: [sql.NVarChar],
  NVARCHAR: [sql.NVarChar],
  Text: [sql.Text],
  TEXT: [sql.Text],
  Int: [sql.Int],
  INT: [sql.Int],
  BigInt: [sql.BigInt],
  BIGINT: [sql.BigInt],
  TinyInt: [sql.TinyInt],
  TINYINT: [sql.TinyInt],
  SmallInt: [sql.SmallInt],
  SMALLINT: [sql.SmallInt],
  Bit: [sql.Bit],
  BIT: [sql.Bit],
  Float: [sql.Float],
  FLOAT: [sql.Float],
  Numeric: [sql.Numeric],
  NUMERIC: [sql.Numeric],
  Decimal: [sql.Decimal],
  DECIMAL: [sql.Decimal],
  Real: [sql.Real],
  REAL: [sql.Real],
  Date: [sql.Date],
  DATE: [sql.Date],
  DateTime: [sql.DateTime],
  DATETIME: [sql.DateTime],
  DateTime2: [sql.DateTime2],
  DATETIME2: [sql.DateTime2],
  DateTimeOffset: [sql.DateTimeOffset],
  DATETIMEOFFSET: [sql.DateTimeOffset],
  SmallDateTime: [sql.SmallDateTime],
  SMALLDATETIME: [sql.SmallDateTime],
  Time: [sql.Time],
  TIME: [sql.Time],
  UniqueIdentifier: [sql.UniqueIdentifier],
  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER: [sql.UniqueIdentifier],
  SmallMoney: [sql.SmallMoney],
  SMALLMONEY: [sql.SmallMoney],
  Money: [sql.Money],
  MONEY: [sql.Money],
  Binary: [sql.Binary],
  BINARY: [sql.Binary],
  VarBinary: [sql.VarBinary],
  VARBINARY: [sql.VarBinary],
  Image: [sql.Image],
  IMAGE: [sql.Image],
  Xml: [sql.Xml],
  XML: [sql.Xml],
  Char: [sql.Char],
  CHAR: [sql.Char],
  NChar: [sql.NChar],
  NCHAR: [sql.NChar],
  NText: [sql.NText],
  NTEXT: [sql.NText],
  TVP: [sql.TVP],
  UDT: [sql.UDT],
  Geography: [sql.Geography],
  GEOGRAPHY: [sql.Geography],
  Geometry: [sql.Geometry],
  GEOMETRY: [sql.Geometry],
  Variant: [sql.Variant],
  VARIANT: [sql.Variant],
  connect: [Function: connect],
  close: [Function: close],
  on: [Function: on],
  off: [Function: removeListener],
  removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
  query: [Function: query],
  batch: [Function: batch],
  Promise: [Getter/Setter] }
```

Comment: do `console.log(sqlDb)` after the require statement and check what it exposes

Comment: I added the log to the end of my question.  The required statement should be accessed from server.js but I am not sure how to reference that so I added it to db.js.  If it will help you can reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#3x-to-4x-changes and look at callbacks

Comment: Docs seem to say "Always attach an error listener to created connection. Whenever something goes wrong with the connection it will emit an error and if there is no listener it will crash your application with an uncaught error."

Comment: I do have err checks in place.  The server was making a successful connection but I had a error when making the request for the recordset. The line that reads var req = new sqlDb.(conn); should read var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);  I left out the Request procedure.  Thank you for you assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a mistake in my code that was causing the problem. The line that reads var req = new sqlDb.(conn); should read var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);  This is the complete corrected db.js:

```
const sqlDb = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')

var settings = require("../settings");
var server = require("./server");

    exports.executeSql = function (sql, callback) {
        var conn = new sqlDb.ConnectionPool(settings.dbConfig);
        conn.connect()
            .then(function () {
                var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
                req.query(sql)
                    .then(function (recordset) {
                        callback(recordset);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        callback(null, err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback(null, err);
            });
    };
```